# Django NoReverseMatch error, reverse function not work with no arguments

Tags: python, django, reverse

this NoReverseMatch error is driving me nuts. I'm using Django 1.6 and I have checked through my urls and it just doesn't work. Please kindly guide me on this.

I basically want to do something deadly simple, just when I submit a html form, I get the data I want and then redirect to a result page, but it just doesn't work...

Here is my index.html file

```
<form name="input" action="{% url 'whatspring:sending' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    Recipient: <input type="text" name="usrname"> 
    <br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
<br>
```

my view.py

```
def index(request):
    return render(request,'springsend/index.html')

def sending(request):
    var = request.POST['usrname']
    doSomethinghere()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('whatspring:results'))

def results(request):
    return render(request,'springsend/send_results.html')
```

then my app urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from springsend import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^results/$', views.results, name='results'),
)
```

and the main urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^send/', include('springsend.urls', namespace="whatspring")),
)
```

I have tried to look into the problem and it seems that the reverse function cannot get the name for the reverse url that I want (i.e. 'results' under the namespace 'whatspring'....)Am I missing something something trival? Please kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `urls.py` (springsend one) doesn't seem to have a url for the `sending` view, that's probably why `{% url 'whatspring:sending' %}` can't find it.

Simply change it to

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from springsend import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    url(r'^sending/$', views.sending, name='sending'), # this line
)
```

Every accessible view needs a url. The user's browser needs to have some address to send things. If it would just send it to your domain without url, Django would have no way to tell which url is requested. Django does not auto-generate these urls (which is probably good).

(The user himself does not need to know this url; you don't need to place any ` links anywhere.)

Comment: thanks, I thought for a functional view would not require the url to be defined. Thanks very much for helping

Comment: I'm afraid you need to set a url for every accessible view; see update.